# Can we create an object of the inner class in the constructor of the outer class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Can we create an object of the inner class in the constructor of the outer class?

Comment: Could you give a code sample?

Comment: There might be corner cases. Such as creating an inner class within the arguments of a call to `this()` or `super()`.

Answer (score 6):

Sure.

```
public class Outer
{
    public Outer()
    {
        Inner inner = new Inner();
    }

    class Inner
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's legal to construct an inner class in constructor of outer class. For example:

```
public class Outer {
    private Inner myInner;

    public Outer() {
        myInner = new Inner();
    }

    public class Inner {

    }
}
```

Have a read through the [Sun Nested Classes Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, then yes, if your using composition.

psudeo-code example:

```
public class Inner(){
  //code
}

public class Outer(){
   Inner foo;

   public Outer() {
      this.foo = new Inner();
   }

}
```